# Disable integration flow - Spring integration

Tags: spring, jms, spring-integration

I need to implement a spring integration flow for error queues handling. The flow needs to be activated based on configuration property as the error queues are not setup for lower environments like DEV.
How can I activate/enable integration flow based on spring configuration property?

my integration flow looks like this:

```
<bean id="error.jms" class="com.xxx.backend.integration.jms.MyMessageListener">
    <property name="destinationName" value="#{queueConfig.getError().queueName()}"/>
    <property name="errorHandler" ref="ErrorHandler"/>
</bean>

<intjms:message-driven-channel-adapter id="errorAdapter"
                                       container="error.jms"
                                       auto-startup="${xxx.backend.jmsAdaptor.autoStart}"
                                       role="systemEndpoint"
                                       channel="error.channel"/>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds more like you need to make yourself familiar with Spring's [Bean Definition Profiles](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/reference/html/core.html#beans-definition-profiles).

So, what you would need is something like this for your config:

```
<beans profile="production">
    <bean id="error.jms" class="com.xxx.backend.integration.jms.MyMessageListener">
      ...
    </bean>

    <intjms:message-driven-channel-adapter id="errorAdapter"
       ...
                                      channel="error.channel"/>

</beans>
```

Then you just need to [activate](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/reference/html/core.html#beans-definition-profiles-enable) it when you start the app in the production., e.g. `-Dspring.profiles.active=production`.